# Microdisplacement has no effect at all

Tags: displacement

I have tried several different configurations, with displacement, vector displacement, different color nodes, non-color, etc.: nothing seem to work. The bump doesn't appear.
Here is the final node config I have set up.
The UV setup is working, I am using it on the other nodes, for the albedo too, so the UV feed is correct.
[image]

Comment: it needs at least 3 conditions: Cycles / vertices that can be displaced / In the Material > Settings > Surface > Displacement, enable Displacement Only (or Displacement + Bump)

Comment: Displacement + Bump is messing up the mesh entirely. I am posting a bug report about this, because there's something strange going on: reverting to BUMP doesn't recover the mesh mess-up.

Comment: @moonboots here is the file: https://pasteall.org/blend/6722016493014ef99387eba93416d72f  
However, I stripped it of EVERYTHING by examining the file. For some reason there are some objects that are ABSOLUTELY NOT USED in the scene, and yet Blender won't delete them nor purge them nor find them anywhere unless I go in the file database. Instead it makes it almost impossible to delete them not even DELETE HIERARCHY will work, the only way is to select them and hit DELETE. Not even ATOMIC DATA MANAGER can find and delete that stuff. I will have to file a question for this too, I guess...

Comment: it works fine, the problem is probably that your object is very low-poly, so it doesn't have a lot to displace. By the way you haven't packed your image so I've tested with another

Comment: @moonboots thank you, I will keep trying. I just found out that the DISP texture is quite ugly and doesn't make much sense. I also tried with the AO though, and that should have given some result... I will try to work on the textures, but it's strange that nothing pops up. I also added the SubSurf modifier, but there is no option for Adaptive Displacement.

Comment: your Mapping scale was at 20, so it made your texture very small + your object is low poly + no Subdivision Surface...

Comment: @moonboots I tried many values, just to see if something popped up.

Answer (score 1):

1. Set the surface displacement to Displacement and Bump or to Dislplacement only (the default is bump, which will not deform the object, and only affect the shading, creating  "fake" relief.
   [image]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvtT0.png)
2. Displacement needs vertices to operate on.
   Here is a simple plane with 4 vertices and dislplacement.
   [image]
    Here's the same plane subdivided 50 times:
   [image]

Comment: But this is supposed to be adaptive. I Don't want millions of polygons, I know how to do a simple displacement. I want to use the function of adaptive microdisplacement starting from a very low amount of polygons.

Comment: Using adaptive subdivision doesn't change anything to this workflow. Except you have to enable it in the render settings and in the subdivision modifier.