# Displacement settings mess up entire mesh

Tags: displacement

This is how the object looks with setting BUMP ONLY:
[image]

This is what happens with DISPLACEMENT AND BUMP:
[image]

And this is my node setup and main question: [Microdisplacement has no effect at all](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209187/microdisplacement-has-no-effect-at-all?noredirect=1#comment353057_209187)

Comment: Does the plane have a (Simple) Subdivision Surface modifier (preferably with 'Adaptive Subdivision' checked? It looks as if your displacement has nothing to chew on.

Comment: it looks like you have not enough topology, plese show the wireframe. Also, why do you ask the same question twice?

Comment: @moonboots because it's not the same question. This looks like a bug to me, and anyway it's a different thing happening.

Comment: @RobinBetts, I added a SubSurf modifier, but I can't find any "adaptive subdivision" option anywhere in the modifier. I am using Cycles of course.

Comment: @RobinBetts You don't need to set the mode to Experimental for shader displacement since a few versions, but you still need it for the adaptive sudbidivisons though. You can try to crank up the subdivision levels and reduce the "Scale" of the displacement node and see what happens. I would advise going back to a simple plane your topology is very bad (lots of N-Gons) causing problems in normal inteprolation https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfeTl.png

Comment: @Gorgious I added the same material to a brand new simple plane: nothing changes. Added SubSurf modifier, enabled, disabled, changed options. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: @Gorgious Oops! Thanks! .. I never use rt disp. without adaptive subdiv, so I missed that. Of course.